# Java Eclipse issue

Tags: java, eclipse, ide

Hello I have just downloaded Eclipse and started studying for my semester final exam.

However when I try to debug I get this:

[image]

How do I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't select the file properly.

Go to the project explorer (in Eclipse), and follow these instructions:

**Right Click** > **Debug As** > **Java Application** or **Debug on Server**

- To open the Package Explorer:

Select **Window** from the top navigation bar:

[image: Top Navigation]

Then follow the instructions below:

**Show View** > **Other...** > Enter 'Package Explorer' in the query bar and select the corresponding result

[image: Package Explorer]

Comment: How do you open the package explorer?

Comment: I've outlined it in my edited answer. Hope this helps :)