# Eclipse isn't showing anything

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, jframe

[The screenshot of my starting eclipse page.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aEwo0.png)
So I'm very new to eclipse. I'm 16 and need it for school, I've been using it for 2 months now.
One of my assignments was to use JFrame and create a GUI which I had to import into eclipse.
However, when I created the java project and then tried to use JFrame it would show me the source(I think that's what its called) but wouldn't let me open the design part.
So then I tried to create a class in a new java project and it wouldn't show me any code so I deleted eclipse and tried to install it again.
Which I did twice and now I just get this screen whenever I open it. I can't find the project explorer and I cant use it.
Please help me to fix and get the screen back to normal with the console and terminal and package explorer visible as well as how to use JFrame properly.

Comment: If you are using Windows, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63910704/java-eclipse-issue/63910792#63910792) will help.

Comment: The views are minimized - the small areas at the right. Click the button in the minimized area to restore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Click **Window** > **Show View** > **Project Explorer** as shown below:

[image]

Similarly, open other views like **Console**, **Problems**, **Outline** etc. (whatever you need).

Comment: Yeah thats solved it but how do I use the design part on jframe

Comment: I recommend you [write code for Swing application](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html) because you will learn the basics much faster that way. However, if you want a GUI development tool, you can install the plugin, [JFormDesigner - Swing GUI Designer](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/jformdesigner-swing-gui-designer)